# Numpy で行の値をランダムに置換したい

Tags: python, numpy, random

現在、python, numpy で作った10 x 10の配列のうち、行の要素7つをランダムに0に置換する方法を探しています。

もし知見をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？
お手数をおかけしますが、宜しくお願い致します。

#### イメージ

**元のデータ:**

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
.
.
.
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

**置換後のデータ:**

```
[[1,0,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,0],
[0,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,3,0,5,0,0,0,9,0],
[0,0,3,0,0,0,7,8,0,0],
.
.
.
[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,10]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

N, M = 10, 7
arr = np.tile(range(1, N+1), (N, 1))
idx = np.random.rand(N, N).argsort(axis=-1)
arr[idx < M] = 0

print(arr)

#
[[ 0  0  0  0  5  0  7  0  0 10]
 [ 0  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0 10]
 [ 1  0  0  0  5  6  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  2  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  4  5  0  7  0  0  0]
 [ 0  2  0  0  0  6  7  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0  0  0  6  0  8  0  0]
 [ 0  2  0  0  0  0  7  0  0 10]
 [ 0  2  0  0  5  6  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  6  7  8  0  0]]
```

Comment: rand で生成した配列にargsort でインデックスを返してnp.where で条件式を当てはめる方法があったのですね。。。ありがとうございました！

Comment: `arr[np.where(idx < M, True, False)] = 0` は `arr[idx < M] = 0` と同等なので変更しました。